# The size of the maximum matching is bounded by the size of the minimum vertex cover

Tags: graph-theory, linear-programming

> Prove, using the weak duality theorem of linear programming, that:
>
> For any graph $G$ (not necessarily bipartite), the size of the maximum matching is at most the size of the minimum vertex cover.

I am a student doing advanced course in combinatorial and actually I do not know where to start in the proof, because this is a general graph, not a bipartite one. So hints would really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem, what have you tried?

Comment: the question is obvious, i need using weak duality theorem to prove that size of Max Matching <= Min Vertex Cover

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Please read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: I am a student doing advanced course in combinatorial and Actually i do not know where to start in the proof, because this is a general graph not bipartite. So hints would really appreciated, Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try to get the question reopened.

Comment: What was wrong with the previous question you posted? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506946/proof-using-weak-duality-of-linear-programming-for-bipartite-graph/506958#506958

Comment: @Antoine How do you know that it's the same user? They may simply be taking the same class.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: Then shouldn't we mark this as duplicate?

Comment: @Antoine I can't do that. I already voted to close for lack of context before said context was provided.

Comment: Hello Lord_Farin, Thanks very much, i am really seeking help or any hints to start digging the proof

Answer (score 2):

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph, let $M\subseteq E(G)$ be a maximum matching of the graph $G$, and let $C\subseteq V(G)$ be the minimum vertex cover of $G$. Since edges in $M$ are disjoint in the sense that no two share an endpoint, each vertex in $v\in C$ covers at most one edge in $M$. Thus $|C|\ge |M|$.

Comment: can you give an example where the cardinality of C and M aren't equal?

Comment: Yes: a $K_{1,4}$ with an edge added between "neighboring" vertices. In that case $|C|=1$ and $|M|=2$.

Comment: thank you, but what does the symbol K mean?

Comment: It's a [star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_(graph_theory)). My example is a star with 4 edges, where you add an edge between a pair of "neighboring" nonadjacent vertices.

Comment: so K(1, 4) in an adjacency list is: {"center": ["1", "2", "3", "4"], "1": ["center"], "2": ["center"], "3": ["center"], "4": ["center"]}. let's add a connect between 1 and 2 which I think is what you're talking about: {"center": ["1", "2", "3", "4"], "1": ["center", "2"], "2": ["center", "1"], "3": ["center"], "4": ["center"]}. The C now is ("center", "2") or ("center", "2"). So cardinality is 2 not 1?

Comment: Oops, you're right. Just take the cycle $C_5$: the size of a minimum cover is $3$ and the size of the maximum matching is $2$.

Comment: so much. Wish I could upvote you twice!